# Java SQL update one table dynamically from another without id

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have two tables like this :

```
Table 1:
Description -- Price 
Apple          10      
Wine           20       
Coffe          5        

Table 2:
Description -- Price -- Number
Pineapple       25       1
Coke            5        1
Orange Juice    8        2
Milk            10       3
```

I want table 1 to look like this ():

```
Description -- Price 
Pineapple       25      
Coke            5       
Orange Juice    8     
Milk            10
```

I have tried this, but I only get the last value returned by the select query (resulting in all rows having the same values).

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("update Table1 set Description=?, Price=? WHERE  (DATEPART(year, date) = "+arraydate[0]+"\n"+ 
                                    "AND    DATEPART(month, date) ="+arraydate[1]+"\n"+
                                    "AND    DATEPART(day, date) ="+arraydate[2]+")"); 
try {
      st=con.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery("select Description,Price from Table2 where number in(35,36)");
      while(rs.next()){
           String desc=rs4.getString("Description");
           Double price=rs4.getDouble("Price");

           ps.clearParameters();
           ps.setString(1,desc);
           ps.setDouble(2,price);
           ps.executeUpdate();
           }
      }
    catch(Exception ex)
  {ex.printStackTrace();}
```

Can anyone help ? Thank you very much.

Comment: I guess the problem is that your update affects multiple rows. This looks really smelly. How are the tables related? Aren't they linked somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do actually.. however updating one table base don another is easy:

```
Update A
    Set A.Price = B.Price 
FROM Table1 as A
    INNER JOIN Table2 AS B
        ON A.Name = B.Name
        and A.Description = B.Description
```

If this does not answer your question please give an example of what you expect the two tables to look like before and after your query.

Comment: This helped, thank you. This was my first time working with a database so huge, so I didnt realize it had a third table relating these two tables... Sorry for bothering, and thank you again.